# How to reset column value to DEFAULT when updating it with DBIx::Class?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

When updating column in postgresql we can reset it value to `DEFAULT`

```
UPDATE table SET column = DEFAULT
```

Is there analogue in DBIx::Class? Just like this:

```
$schame->result_set( 'table' )->update({ column => DEFAULT })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to *ilmari*. I need `ref` to use literal SQL:

```
$schame->result_set( 'table' )->update({ column => \'DEFAULT' })
```

Comment: Note that this is now engine specific. You will not be able to port it to say SQLite.

Comment: @simbabque: Is there non engine specific way?

Comment: I don't think so. If a maintainer doesn't know then probably not. I don't think sqlite or MySQL can even do that. Oracle maybe.

Comment: If you use DBIx::Class consistently, you should have that default in the column_info. In which case you can update to that.

Comment: @bytepusher: If you mean `default_value` that is different thing. and `->update({ column => undef })` will not work if `is_nullable => 0`

Comment: @EugenKonkov: That is what I was referring to. And that is non engine- specific information stored in the model. If it's not in the model, you need to use an engine-specific way of getting it out.